# Solving a system of equations with additional condition

Tags: systems-of-equations

Suppose I have the following system I want to solve

\begin{equation}
        \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{12} & 1\\
-\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1\\
-\frac{5}{12} & \frac{7}{12} & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\delta_0\\
\delta_1\\
\delta_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1.5000 \\
1.6667\\
1.8333
\end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

Where additionally $\delta_0<2\delta_1$

If I used a program such as R and Matlab to try to solve this. Unfortunately, to find a solution of the system. This is because I am unable/ do not know how to incorporate the additional condition $\delta_0<2\delta_1$ when solving the system.

I would like to find the values of $\delta_0,
\delta_1,
\delta_2$. Unfortunately I get stuck.

Comment: Could you just solve the linear system first, then amongst the solutions to that system figure out which ones also satisfy your inequality?  Particularly if you make $\delta_0$ or $\delta_1$ the free variable of your solution it seems you could do this.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you

Comment: The determinant of your matrix is $0$.  Do you know what that means?

Comment: That the columns of my matrix are linearly dependent?